# Jquery AJAX request is uploading the data two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My AJAX request is uploading my form data two times into the database.

This is the AJAX function

```
function uploadProjects() {
  let projectName = $('#projectName').val();
  let description = $('#description').val();
  let estimatedTime = $('#estimatedTime').val();
  let actualTime = $('#actualTime').val();

  const formData = {
    projectName: projectName,
    description: description,
    estimatedTime: estimatedTime,
    actualTime: actualTime,
  };
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/WBS/php/api/objects/Project.php',
    data: formData,
    success: (response) => {
      console.log(`The data ${JSON.stringify(response)} has been uploaded`);
      $('#alert').fadeIn(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          $('#alert').fadeOut();
        }, 5000);
      });
    },
    error: (response) => {
      console.error(
        `Something went wrong uploading the data ${JSON.stringify(response)}`
      );
      $('#alertFailed').fadeIn(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          $('#alertFailed').fadeOut();
        }, 5000);
      });
    },
  });
}
```

I call this function like so

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#addProject').one('click', () => {
    uploadProjects();
  });
});
```

i call the function on this html button

```
<button id="addProject" form="js-projects" class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add a project</button>
```

Inspecting the POST request in my browser (Firefox) i can see the request is only made once to my PHP file, which uploads said data.

Upon inspecting the database the data has been uploaded two times.

A: issue was on the back-end, was executing my query two times. stupid oversight on my behalf

Comment: Since you post it only once, than the problem is inside Project.php

Comment: Are you sure that the default event is not hapening? you could be submiting it and send it via ajax as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```js
$(function() => {
  $("#formID").on("submit",uploadProjects);
});
```

and then

```
function uploadProjects(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // if you do not want to submit again:
  $('#addProject').hide();

  let projectName = $('#projectName').val();
  .....
)
```

If it still saves twice, then the issue is on the backend